# .Net Do I really need migrations?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

It's my first .net app from scratch. I'm used to .net, c# and mvc but I'm trying to learn all of the tricks such as migrations.

Originally, I had seeding setup to run always. It was working great, my changes were always there with my new data. Then came the SimpleMembership. I figured, I can't drop the DB anymore because I'll lose my Membership tables. So I found out about migrations. Great let's do it.

What I understand is that every time you make a change to the models, you require a new migration to be created. I would like my DB to stay up to date with my models always. I don't want to be calling update-database all the time. I've heard something about automatic migration which updates the DB fields automatically.

**Question:** 
Is it possible to setup migrations to automatically update the DB on model change and not have to create a new migration every time?

Comment: I always wondered this myself. I don't do much with Code-First (I'm usually dealing with an existing database). The few times I've played with it, I ended up running into a similar situation and asking myself the same questions.

Comment: I don't see how it could. `Add-Migration` can take a guess at what changes happened in your model but its not always going to be correct. Suppose you renamed a property. It can often guess that you added a column and deleted a column, but it can't guess a rename and it can't guess that it needs to transfer data from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC if we want to add properties in database migrations are compulsory because it helps to create a table easily. As per my point of view migrations are easiest way to add tables in database. Most importantly we use migrations because it automatically updates the database schema without losing existing data and other database object.

```
add-migration --name
```